# Posting data using node-fetch in a react component malfunction

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I'm simply trying to post json data to an express server using node-fetch. I know the post function in the server works because I've tested it in git bash. I'm also doing this in a react component.

Here's the fetch code:

```
   addBug(bug) {
    let bugsModified = this.state.bugs.slice()
    bug.id = this.state.bugs.length + 1
    bugsModified.push(bug)

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/bugs', {method: 'POST', body: bugsModified})
      .then(res => res.status === 200 && this.setState({bugs: bugsModified}))
  }
```

The {body: bugsModified} doesn't seem to send the server anything. Here's the code from the server:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/api/bugs', (req, res) => {
  const bug = req.body
  bugs.push(bug)
  res.json(bug)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('connected...'))
```

If anyone can help me figure out how to post actual data using node-fetch, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FYI I would ensure that your content headers are populated:

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': new Buffer(body).length
}
```